# Select images and display using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This will select the targeted files and cycles through selected files and stops on the last file. How can the images be displayed without being over written?

```
//Function below is in the DOM area
function showDirectory(){
   var myFiles = document.getElementById("files");
   for(var i=0;i<=myFiles.files.length; i++){
   var x = myFiles.files[i].name;
   document.getElementById("demo1").src= x;
   }
}
//This is in a div in the body
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple/>
<button onclick="showDirectory();">Show files in the Directory</button>
<img id="demo1" src=""  style="width: 40px; height: 40px;"><br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax `document.createElement()` is used to actually create new DOM elements, so that you don't have to override old ones. In your case, replace `document.getElementById("demo1").src= x;` with

```
let e = document.createElement("img");
e.src = x;
document.getElementById("demo1").appendChild(e);
```

This code will create a new DOM element of type image, it will set its source to whatever your for loop outputs, and then it will append the img to the div that you have created.

Comment: Wow, that did populate the images however the styling is off is there a way to apply a style to the output? I'm shooting for thumb nail size. Thanks for you response above Luca

Comment: Yes there is @BenG - to apply style to each image you can use the `.style` property. So, to make each of your images 50 pixels high you would add the line `e.style.height = "50px";` after the line `e.src = x;` This will preserve the aspect ratio of the image while shrinking it. To change the size to the desired size just change `50px` to a different pixel value. `20px` will make it smaller and `70px` will make it bigger.